# Adding a vector as a new column to a matrix

Tags: python

I have a matrix with 6 rows and 5 columns, and a 1d vector of length 6 that I want to add to my matrix as as new 6th column so that I end up with an 6x6 matrix.

The 1d-vector

```
[0.77777777777777779, 0.061224489795918366, 0.86864406779661019, 0.66666666666666663, 0.96470588235294119, 83.333333333333343]
```

The matrix

```
[[  42.            0.            6.            0.            6.        ]
 [   0.            3.            8.            0.           38.        ]
 [   6.            0.          205.            0.           25.        ]
 [   0.            0.            2.            4.            0.        ]
 [   1.            0.            8.            0.          246.        ]
 [   0.85714286    1.            0.89519651    1.            0.78095238]]
```

I've tried `np.hstack` but that does not work for this job.

Comment: How about `np.concatenate`  ?

Answer (score 2):

The reason why `np.hstack([matrix, vector])` doesn't work is because the shapes don't fit each other:

```
>>> vector.shape
(6,)
>>> matrix.shape
(6, 5)
```

But if you make `vector` a *column* vector with `vector[:, np.newaxis]` then `np.hstack` can handle the shapes:

```
>>> matrix = np.arange(30).reshape(6,5)
>>> vector = -np.ones(6)
>>> matrix
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
       [20, 21, 22, 23, 24],
       [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]])
>>> vector
array([-1., -1., -1., -1., -1., -1.])
>>> vector[:, np.newaxis]
array([[-1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.],
       [-1.]])
>>> vector[:, np.newaxis].shape
(6, 1)
>>> np.hstack([matrix, vector])
Rückverfolgung (innerste zuletzt):
  Python-Shell, prompt 23, line 1
  File "C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\shape_base.py", line 293, in hstack
    return _nx.concatenate(arrs, 1)
builtins.ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions
>>> np.hstack([matrix, vector[:, np.newaxis]])
array([[  0.,   1.,   2.,   3.,   4.,  -1.],
       [  5.,   6.,   7.,   8.,   9.,  -1.],
       [ 10.,  11.,  12.,  13.,  14.,  -1.],
       [ 15.,  16.,  17.,  18.,  19.,  -1.],
       [ 20.,  21.,  22.,  23.,  24.,  -1.],
       [ 25.,  26.,  27.,  28.,  29.,  -1.]])
```

Comment: Hey Michael. Thank you very much. Got it working now!